# Toplink Objects not showing up under the Toplink Map node in JDeveloper

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, toplink, jdeveloper

for some reason I cannot see any of the generated objects under the TL Map. See the included image (Sorry but it will not render using the community wiki software....

http://img261.imageshack.us/my.php?image=nothingundernodetn5.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, this is the problem:
The tutorial shows that the Toplink map can be expanded. Apparently it cannot be in Jdeveloper 10.1.3.0.4. You need to select the Toplink map, then find the STRUCTURE panel. This is now how you would expand the Toplink map.